# Problems connecting to OpenStack-horizon

Tags: openstack, juju, openstack-horizon

After installing OpenStack with LXD on GoogleCloud (Ubuntu 18.04) using conjure-up, I am unable to access horizon (via website).

Per other people’s suggestions, I tried;

> ‘juju expose openstack-dashboard’

and

> ‘sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 35.231.26.151 --dport 80
>   -j DNAT --to-destination 10.213.223.246’

but horizon is still unavailable. I also activated **net.ipv4.ip-forward=1** but still no response. Any suggestion on What else I should check? Thanks.